# When is sum of $n$ unit vectors is also a unit vector?

Tags: vectors

Can we think about particular constraints for the case when $n$ unit vectors add up to give another unit vector?

Leaving the trivial $n=1$ case, for $n=2$, we know that the angle between them must be $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. For $n=3$, from what I have seen [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wo8rqczqti), (and after proving it the hard way), it appears that 2 out of the 3 vectors must be opposite. But my method of graphical analysis breaks down after that. How can we generalize this for arbitrary $n$? More clearly, what restrictions can we put on the nature of the unit vectors being added?

Additional: Right after writing this question down, I have got a new idea. If adding $n$ unit vectors gives another unit vector, then they (with the resultant unit vector) must form a $n+1$ sided polygon with unit length sides. This makes the proof for $n=3$ much easier. Can we extend this idea for higher $n$? Other approaches are also welcome.

Comment: Your idea is fine. For $n=3$ you get a rhombus. But for $n\ge4$ you can have even concave polygons. So I'm not sure what constraints you are looking for.

Comment: Are you referring to unit vectors in 2D, 3D or N-dimensional spaces?

Comment: What about taking $n$ vectors forming edges of a regular $(n+1)$-gon?

Comment: @user I had initially thought of the question in the 2D sense, but it would be OK too if someone has ideas regarding higher dimensions

Comment: @SohamSaha Yes indeed we can extend to higher dimensions.

Comment: @SohamSaha If you have some more question please don't hesitate to ask for any clarification. Bye

Answer (score 0):

Yes the idea that the problem is equivalent to $n+1$ unit vectors which sum is equal to zero allows to obtain a general solution.

We can visualize the unit vectors as a closed chain with the first vector starting from the origin and the last vector ending at the origin. Moreover, as a mechanical analogy, we can imagine the chain of vectors as a chain of rigid bars connected at the ends by pinned connections.

For a $N$ dimensional space, each of the $v$ vertices of the chain has $N$ degree of freedom (DOF) from which we need to subtract the $N$ DOF for the fixed origin and the $e$ DOF due to the fixed length of the edges. In this way, we can conclude that any configuration for the chain has:

> $$vN-N-e=(v-1)N-e$$

residual DOF.

---

Here is some example for $N=2$ and $N=3$
[image]

Comment: In $\mathbb R^2$, a unit vector is determined by just one number (generally in $\mathbb R^N$, it is determined by $N-1$ numbers giving the direction), so I think the degrees of freedom calculation needs to be reconsidered

Comment: I’ll add some concrete example and sketch to better explain the idea. Thanks

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Let me know if now it’s clear or if I’m missing your point. Regards

Comment: Maybe the confusion arised because for a typo I used the term edge instead vertex, now fixed.

Comment: "each vertex of the chain has $N$ degree of freedom": Though I am not familiar with DOF, but still, consider a unit sphere. Then any vertex on the unit sphere (i.e., an 3D unit vector) can be expressed using only two variables: $\theta$ and $\phi$ (polar coordinates). What am I missing?

Comment: @SohamSaha I've now introduced the number of vertices (v) in order to consider more general cases. I've also added some example for N=2 and N=3.